# Checkbox is not getting selected while running but it gets selected in debug mode(eclipse)

Tags: checkbox, selenium-webdriver, xdebug

I have tried running this code on both the browsers but the checkbox is not getting selected while running but it does get selected in debug mode. Please find the code:[Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYCnl.png)

Comment: Are you getting a particular error when running?

Comment: No, i am not getting any error.

Comment: Are you sure then that it's not already selected and you're deselecting it?

Comment: The checkbox is not selected by default, i am very sure about it.

Comment: Have you got the relevant html as well to go with it? Hard to see what's going on without the relevant code.